# Where is the source code of the Gradle task "createDebugCoverageReport" in an Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I've been searching in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/ but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it by ctrl-clicking on `testCoverageEnabled` in the `<app>/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

It's at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/coverage/JacocoReportTask.groovy